# Why do I get GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown with notify-send?

Tags: 22.04, notify-send, libnotify

When attempting to display any notification with `notify-send` I get:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: 
The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
```

I also noticed that `$HOME/.dbus/` disappeared. It was working before
although I use `notify-send` only via scripts that are run by `cron`. I have `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus` in my `crontab`. `notify-send` is to notify me only in case of an emergency - and there was none as far as I know.
I update my Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS with `apt` every twelve
hours, could such update be responsible for the issue?
I have `libnotify-bin` installed. I've found people [describing a similar issue](https://github.com/gnome-pomodoro/gnome-pomodoro/issues/344) but am hesitant to apply their fix as I do not know much about `dbus` and `freedesktop`.

How should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
```

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```

Comment: This works, but also requires `sudo apt install -y notification-daemon`, which provides `/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon`. (This is for Debian 12.)